# Not able to use react-native-vector-icons in react-native project?

Tags: react-native, gradle, react-native-vector-icons

I have initialized a react native project using the command

```
npx react-native@latest init tambola_React_Native
```

Then I installed react-native-vector-icons using command

```
npm i react-native-vector-icons
```

then I followed the guide for android setup provided in npm page.

android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle")

/**
 * This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
 * By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
 */
react {
    /* Folders */
    //   The root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives. Default is '..'
    // root = file("../")
    //   The folder where the react-native NPM package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native
    // reactNativeDir = file("../node_modules/react-native")
    //   The folder where the react-native Codegen package is. Default is ../node_modules/@react-native/codegen
    // codegenDir = file("../node_modules/@react-native/codegen")
    //   The cli.js file which is the React Native CLI entrypoint. Default is ../node_modules/react-native/cli.js
    // cliFile = file("../node_modules/react-native/cli.js")

    /* Variants */
    //   The list of variants to that are debuggable. For those we're going to
    //   skip the bundling of the JS bundle and the assets. By default is just 'debug'.
    //   If you add flavors like lite, prod, etc. you'll have to list your debuggableVariants.
    // debuggableVariants = ["liteDebug", "prodDebug"]

    /* Bundling */
    //   A list containing the node command and its flags. Default is just 'node'.
    // nodeExecutableAndArgs = ["node"]
    //
    //   The command to run when bundling. By default is 'bundle'
    // bundleCommand = "ram-bundle"
    //
    //   The path to the CLI configuration file. Default is empty.
    // bundleConfig = file(../rn-cli.config.js)
    //
    //   The name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
    // bundleAssetName = "MyApplication.android.bundle"
    //
    //   The entry file for bundle generation. Default is 'index.android.js' or 'index.js'
    // entryFile = file("../js/MyApplication.android.js")
    //
    //   A list of extra flags to pass to the 'bundle' commands.
    //   See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/commands.md#bundle
    // extraPackagerArgs = []

    /* Hermes Commands */
    //   The hermes compiler command to run. By default it is 'hermesc'
    // hermesCommand = "$rootDir/my-custom-hermesc/bin/hermesc"
    //
    //   The list of flags to pass to the Hermes compiler. By default is "-O", "-output-source-map"
    // hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
}

/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.tambola_react_native"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tambola_react_native"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation("com.facebook.react:flipper-integration")
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

android/settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'tambola_React_Native'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
```

Then I executed the command
`npx react-native run-android`
and I am getting the following error

```
kherkatarybhaskar@Bhaskars-MacBook-Air tambola_React_Native % npx react-native run-android
info Installing the app...

> Task :react-native-vector-icons:processDebugManifest
package="com.oblador.vectoricons" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/kherkatarybhaskar/Downloads/ReactNative/tambola_React_Native/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported, and the value is ignored.
Recommendation: remove package="com.oblador.vectoricons" from the source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/kherkatarybhaskar/Downloads/ReactNative/tambola_React_Native/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.

> Task :react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

**Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.**

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
36 actionable tasks: 36 executed

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/kherkatarybhaskar/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/kherkatarybhaskar/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7056ed491d13671bf4afd0abdfd4273b/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/kherkatarybhaskar/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7056ed491d13671bf4afd0abdfd4273b/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:androidJdkImage'. > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}. > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/kherkatarybhaskar/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar. > Error while executing process /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/kherkatarybhaskar/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7056ed491d13671bf4afd0abdfd4273b/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/kherkatarybhaskar/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7056ed491d13671bf4afd0abdfd4273b/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules} * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```